# Unable to update data in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue when I click OK on the edit page to update a record; it just redirects to the other page and the updated record is not shown. It should redirect back to the page with the update but what happens now is that it returns blank. This is what I have so far. Question was edited with the issueitem method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Issue</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-horizontal">


                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new { @id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.expense_acccount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })                        

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.expense_acccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new { @id = "price", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="OK" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IssueItem","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" />


 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        getIssue.item = getIssue.items[id - 1];//Returns the requested item for editing
        return View(getIssue);
    }




    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {
        int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
        getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;

        return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", new {id=indx});

    }

     public ActionResult IssueItem() {
     Session.Clear(); 
 IssueDAO dbData = new IssueDAO(); 
    getIssue.docNumber = string.Concat("IS", DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmddhhmmss")); 
    getIssue.docType = "Issue"; getIssue.inventory_acccount = 5520; ViewBag.StoresReps = dbData.SelectEmployeesByDept("Stores"); 
    getIssue.item = new Item(); 
    return View(getIssue); }

private Issue getIssue { 
get { 
Issue issue = (Issue)Session["Issue"];
 if (issue == null) { issue = new Issue(); 
Session["Issue"] = issue; } return issue;
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is your `IssueItem()` method? And you not passing anything to it anyway (and put relevant code in your question, not in comments)

Comment: Your'e not passing any data to the IssueItem View

Comment: Ok I have updated the question

Comment: Hey @ConfusedShark; I was wondering if you could share with me what had I missed

Comment: why are you returning     **getIssue.item = new Item();**

Comment: when the user adds an item

Comment: as previous persons point out that here is the problem  return RedirectToAction("IssueItem");

Comment: yeah..you are not passing the issue you got from the form....& rather creating a new issue....hence no update...cos the data isn't getting passed

Comment: @StephenMuecke; is it possible to help me out because I'm still getting it. please

Comment: @ConfusedShark; I was hoping you could assist me please; I'm unsure of what to do next

Comment: @StephenMuecke; i have updated the question with what i now have however when redirect there is no data shown; how do i get back the data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once when I added the controller name in the RedirectToAction it seem's to work fine

```
public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {
        int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
        getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;

        return RedirectToAction("IssueItem","your_controller_name");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the existing model to getIssue .

```
public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {      
        return RedirectToAction("IssueItem" ,issue);
    }
```

then use the model issue to pass the form information

```
public ActionResult IssueItem(Issue issue) {
     // use issue
  int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
  getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;

 // do the rest..
 return View(getIssue); 
}
```

Comment: so what about this part; public ActionResult Edit(int id) don't I need it

Comment: // do the rest.. what are you refferring to

Comment: your form post will always return a model issue....hence   **Edit(int id)** might never called

Comment: & always decorate post action methods with a     [HttpPost]

Comment: I get this error: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

Comment: you got it after removing....which param ??... it happened because the the post action controller with  model couldnt be found

Comment: i remove the one with int id

Comment: ok...so your form was earlier posting to the edit with the int ID...which is again very bad

Comment: can you post the code of your entire .cs page & .cshtml page

Comment: entire pages won't hold

Comment: let us continue this in a chat

Comment: Hey @Rohitas; why is it bad posting to the edit with the int ID

Comment: because..when you post the form...the data is contained in the model... so the post method should be in position to accept a model.... if we just send (int id)..then that would mean we are only posting an ID...but we are actually posting the whole model

Comment: but is just one record i'm trying to update not the whole model

Comment: if you just want to update one record...then you could do it by Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm

Comment: that way your page wont be refreshed & that one piece you would want to update will also get updated

Comment: how could I do that..give an example please

Comment: [this artilce](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/ajax-beginform-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/) ....keep in mind **UpdateTargetId**

Comment: so it is not possible to use Html.BeginForm  to edit one record. don't think i really understand the ajax

Comment: ajax.beginform i'm not getting it

Comment: I will explain tomorrow buddy...its 12 in the night in my country

Comment: oh sorry wish you could tell me what I should change here return RedirectToAction("IssueItem"); since you said it wasn't passing anything

Comment: Hey is it possible to help me out now

Comment: Yeah... I would love to ...could you push your entire code to github

Comment: could move the conversation to a chat that way I can send the code and more explanation can be done there

Answer (score 0):

Rohitas has made some good points but there are few things missing from your code

Razor  needs the model stated

Razor Code based on your example

```
@model Issue
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Issue</h4>
            <hr/>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            <fieldset>
            <div class="form-horizontal">


                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new {@id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly",})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.expense_acccount, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new {@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.expense_acccount, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new {@id = "price", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly",})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            <input type="submit" value="OK" name="OK" class="btn btn-default"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("IssueItem", "Issue")' " class="btn btn-default"/>

        </div>
    }
```

Controller is missing [HttpPost] on edit postback andwill always do same thing regardless if data valid or not. Not sure how you are getting the correct result to edit as not clear in example.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        // didnt make sense 
        // getIssue.item = getIssue.items[id - 1];

        Issue getIssue =  IssueReposiroty.GetIssueById(id) // exaqmple as no idea hgow retrieved 
        return View(getIssue);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
    {
        If(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // process saving of updated item

            // can pass id or pass model to save retrieving again
            return RedirectToAction("IssueItem", issue);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please make sure you have filled in all required fields.");
        }

        return View(issue);
    }

    public ActionResult IssueItem(Issue issue)
    {
        return View(issue);
    }
```

Unlikely to completely resolve but will hopefully point you in right direction.  The Microsoft MVC tutorials are good for learning basics like this and I would recommend working through them https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview